# Problems downloading gmp due to the makefiles

Tags: makefile, gmp

I am on a Windows computer but working with the cygwin subsystem.
I have followed some manuals on how to download gmp. I have therefor downloaded, unzipped and configured the gmp-6.2.1 file, but i come onto problems in the "make" step.
In the gmp-6.2.1 file there are two makefiles, and when i try to use "make" on them i get:

```
$ make -f Makefile.in
Makefile.in:15: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Where line 15 in Makefile.in is

```
@SET_MAKE@
```

and

```
$ make -f Makefile.am
Makefile.am:126: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Where line 126-130 in Makefile.am is

```
if WANT_CXX
GMPXX_HEADERS_OPTION = gmpxx.h
pkgconfig_DATA += gmpxx.pc
endif
```

Do you know if I need to change anything in the makefiles, or something else?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`Makefile.in` and `Makefile.am` are not makefiles.  It is erroneous to use `make -f` to try to interpret them as such.  These are contributors to *building* a makefile for the project.

You're looking at a project with a GNU build system.  The standard procedure for building such a project is to

1. run the `./configure` script to generate one or more makefiles and perhaps other files, then
2. run `make` in the same working directory to build the project, then
3. run `make install` in that directory to install the built result to the system.

There are variations and embellishments that can be made, but that's the basic pattern.  Nowhere should you need to use `make`'s `-f` option.

If the instructions you're following are any good then they will have covered this at least briefly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

I tried to run the `make` command but then got
`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`
so something probably went wrong with the `./configure` which I going to take a look at.

Comment: @MathiasRabing, it is entirely possible that `./configure` failed, and therefore did not create a makefile.  If so, then it probably outputted a diagnostic message describing the issue (most often, inability to find a required library or header).  If the nature of the problem is not clear from the output alone, then `config.log` should provide details about exactly what failed.